# Laravel extending Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase with custom namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm trying to set up unit tests for my Laravel (5.2) API project. Before I use the unit tests I'd like to define a custom namespace for them so I created the `namespace Test;` in the default `TestCase.php` file. Like so:

```
namespace Test;

class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
  ...
}
```

Then I created a folder `UnitTests` under the `tests` folder and put my unit tests in that folder with the following namespace:

```
namespace Test\UnitTests;

use Test\TestCase;

class CreateAccountTest extends TestCase
{
  ...
}
```

Now when I want to run my unit tests I get the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Test\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase' not found in /var/www/ops/tests/TestCase.php on line 6`

So basically, Laravel thinks the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`class is found within the Test namespace instead of the `Illuminate`namespace from Laravel.

I also have the following autoload configured in the `composer.json` file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "tests"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Test\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
}
```

I've also tried running both commands with no success:

- `php artisan config:cache`
- `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: shouldn't it be `class TestCase extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` ?

Comment: That's correct! Silly because I thought this file was created by Laravel, maybe I accidentally removed the slash or something. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem!

Comment: Please do not use comments as answers @xmike otherwise this question becomes useless as it is unanswered!

Comment: hm... never thought about that.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @xmike mentioned in the comments of the question I didn't add a backslash to the namespace.

So instead of

```
class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
```

it should be

```
class TestCase extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
```